# ¿Por qué no hace bien la multiplicación cuando es mayor a 40?

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class JavaApplication8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int salario;
        float total;

        salario = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("Digite las horas trabajadas"));

        if (salario > 0) {
            if (salario <= 40000) {
                total = salario * 16;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Su salario total es: "
                        + total);
            } else {
                total = (40 * 16) + ((salario - 40) * 20);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Su salario total es: "
                        + total);
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "No puede introducir salarios negativos!");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: A que te refieres con que no la realiza bien? en que parte del código, se más especifico por favor Santiago. Da un ejemplo de lo que ingresas y que resultado tienes.

Comment: en el : else total=(40*16)+((salario-40)*20); // en esta parte en vez de multiplicar por 20 multiplica por 16 , si pongo 45 me deberia dar 740 y me da 720

Comment: Eso es lógico amigo , 45 es mayor que 40000 por eso entra al primer `If` después de validar que es mayor que 0

Comment: aaaa ok muchas gracias, no me habia fijado de ese error gracias

Answer (score 1):

Para entrar a el `else` se debe cumplir que primeramenta salario sea mayor que 0 y posteriormente que:

```
 salario > 40000
```

por esa razón si el valor de salario es 40, no se realiza la operación:

```
total = salario * 16;
```

trata con un valor mayor como 40001 y seguramente se ejecutara la operación deseada.

```
 total = (40 * 16) + ((salario - 40) * 20);
```